# Make /www/html/ permanantly accessable to my web browses to install drupal sites

Tags: command-line, server, apache2, filesystem

I am using

```
chown -Rf www-data:www-data /www/html/*
```

and

```
chmod -Rf 777 /www/html/*
```

to give my drupal cores permission to create a new site.(with and without *)

I have also tried every variant of the above commands I could find as well.
However every-time I put a new drupal core into the html directory I have to issue the commands all over again or drupal can't access the files it needs.

I know this can be done because xampp, mampp and acquia dev desktop doesn't need me to go into the directory and change ownership and permissions every time I add a new drupal core to it. So how do I make this permanant on my ubuntu 16.04 server I use for home developement? I just want to download a new drupal core, make the database and install a new site by drush or graphically without having to also renew the chown and chmod commands everytime? I'm a newbie to servers and have spent hundreds of hours learning but can't find what I'm either doing wrong or just not doing in my server.

Please help and thanks for your help.

Comment: are you doing them as root user ?

Comment: Yes using sudo not logged in as root.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are generally not propagated by the directory that files are being copied into, rather new permissions are controlled by the user's umask. However when you copy a file from one location to another it's a bit of a special case where the user's umask is essentially ignored and the existing permissions on the file are preserved. Understanding this concept is the key to getting what you want [(from here)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115246/file-inheriting-permission-of-directory-it-is-copied-in).

So when you are copying a new directory to /var/www/html you should use:

```
cp --no-preserve=all -r ~/drupal/ /var/www/html/new-drupul/
```

Another thing is setting sticky bit on the /var/www/html directory:

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/html
```

Now when you create new files within /var/www/html or extract a new drupul there they will inherit their parent owners. you can read more about sticky bit [here](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/managing-file-system-security/sticky-bit.html).

If you are interested to read more about permissions of apache and /var/www/html [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver) will give you all the answers.

Comment: Thank you this is new to me and I really appreciate it. I'll study the sticky. I'm still in the dark about copying. I believe there's some kind of setting in a conf file somewhere but don't understand servers well enough yet to understand why xampp and the others don't need special attributes just drag and drop in windows does it. Thanks again this gives me new avenues to study. :)

Comment: chomod seemed to be a typo my server said no such command. So I changed it to "sudo chmod g+s /var/www/html" and the server seemed to like that. :)

Comment: Yes it was a typo, I edited my answer. things works different in Gnu/Linux from windows. you should read a little bit about how permissions works in linux. if this solution worked for you, you can accept it as an correct answer. it will help others to find their way easier ;)